# C++ Making 2D game graphics with GTK+

Tags: c++, user-interface, graphics, gtk

I am interested in making a GUI-intensive strategy game with C++ and GTK+. What I would like to know is how feasible it would be to add 2D game graphics to a GTK program. Basically I would be wanting something like a game screen, with interactable 2D graphics, flanked by menus and the ability to navigate to other screens that would be GUI only.

Note that I have never used GTK before, nor have I before programed a GUI (nor graphics either).

Answer (score 5):

It's certainly *possible* with GTK, but you have to ask yourself whether you're using the right tool for the job. Use Clutter, which is much more suited to animation and integrates with GTK; or perhaps better yet, use a game programming toolkit.

[Here](http://chrislord.net/index.php/2010/07/29/pill-popping-and-happy-wombats/)'s an example of two non-intensive proof-of-concept games written with Clutter, with links to their source code.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible. I did it with GTK and Vala some time ago. Here is a [blog post](http://interhacker.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/hacking-in-vala/) I wrote about it. Basically it's very much like the games you make with Java and Swing. Just override the `expose` signal and create a `timer` for regular redraws. [Here](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pygtktutorial/snake/)'s an article on developing a 2D Snake game in PyGTK.

In pseudocode, all you do for the game infrastructure is:

```
start()
{
    tick_timer( 1.0 / FPS );
    load_all_sprites_etc();
}

tick()
{
    update();
    game_board.expose(); // game_board is a GTKWidget, preferably a DrawingArea
}

expose_event()  // connected to game_board
{
    drawing_code();
}

update() 
{
    game_physics();
    game_logic();
}
```